# '90s/'00s sci-fi anthology TV series episode involving a woman who kills men by having sex with them

Tags: story-identification, tv

The episode I recall opens at this lady's cabin/house by a lake. She is in the water with a guy. A bunch of fog starts in the water. Having sex with men kills them. She thinks maybe this time is different, but it isn't. I think she kind of tried to talk to him about it in a way. Then she is just bitter and doesn't care. Maybe her mom tries to talk to her about it.

She was wearing red. White chick with dark hair.

'90s/'00s sci-fi anthology aired on Saturdays at about 3pm. First half hour was the week's new episode, the second half hour was the previous week's episode.

I thought it was the same show as an episode of *Beyond Reality*, but doesn't look like it.

I watched it in the American North East. More likely in the 90s. It must have been on cable. I can't recall if there was a host type setup.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the approximate year in which you actually watched this? Also, which country did you watch it in, and if you recall, on which channel were you likely to have seen it on?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: In the American North East. More likely in the 90s. It must have been on cable.

Comment: Night Visions and PSI Factor (S1) were half hour anthology series in that time frame, but none of the episode descriptions seem to match.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like the "Outer Limits" episode "Caught in the Act".  With Alyssa Milano  (Airdate is right.)

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667872/

Comment: 92% sure it is not. Since my episode opens with sexual behavior and The Outer Limits one has her being celibate.

Comment: Been a long time since I saw it, but it seemed to check the boxes.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it is *[Beyond Reality](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101046/)* (1991–1993)! The episode is **"[Siren Song](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0523456/?ref_=ttep_ep17)"**.

From IMDB:

> J.J. starts dating a female colleague just as a string of unexplained murders begins. Laura thinks that succubus, a lust demon, is behind it. Their new young assistant, Celia, helps her investigate.

I just bought it used on DVD.

I thought it might have aired on USA Network; it did.